# Android: Refresh ListView after AsyncTask stops ArrayList filling and displaying

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-asynctask

In the code below, the `displayList()` method is responsible for filling an ArrayList with contents from a database table, depending on the purpose of the viewing, and then displaying this in a ListView.

However, the first time running a new version of the database or the first ever run of the program, when a new instance of the Database Manipulator class (`ManipulateDatabase` in this case) is created, an AsyncTask runs to import preliminary data to the database, and this interrupts the ArrayList being filled and the ListView being displayed. Consequently, after the AsyncTask is finished, the ListView appears empty.

My question is, how can I solve the problem so that after the AsyncTask has finished, the ListView is displayed with the correct contents? I would be very grateful for a useful response.

The relevant code is shown below.

**`displayList()`**

```
private void displayList() {
        try {
            System.out.println("DISPLAYING HERE");
            md = new ManipulateDatabase(this, new ProgressDialog(this));
            if (purpose.equals("ViewNovel")) {
                setTitle("Novels");
                listContents = md.getPieces("0");
                System.out.println(purpose);
            } else if (purpose.equals("TestNovel")) {
                setTitle("Novels");
                listContents = md.getPieces("0");
                System.out.println(purpose);

            } else if (purpose.equals("TestPlay")) {
                setTitle("Plays");
                listContents = md.getPieces("1");
                System.out.println(purpose);

            } else if (purpose.equals("ViewPlay")) {
                setTitle("Plays");
                listContents = md.getPieces("1");
                System.out.println(purpose);
            } else if (purpose.equals("ViewStats")) {
                setTitle("Statistics");
                listContents = md.getPieces("0");
                listContents.addAll(md.getPieces("1"));
                System.out.println(purpose);
            } else if (purpose.endsWith("/Char")) {
                int point = purpose.indexOf("/");
                String rest = purpose.substring(point + 1, purpose.length());
                point = rest.indexOf("/");
                String title = rest.substring(0, point);
                listContents = md.getElements(title, "1", "");
                setTitle(title + " - Characters");
                System.out
                        .println("Tried to get Char elements and put in array");
                System.out.println(purpose);

            }

            else if (purpose.endsWith("/Theme")) {
                int point = purpose.indexOf("/");
                String rest = purpose.substring(point + 1, purpose.length());
                point = rest.indexOf("/");
                String title = rest.substring(0, point);
                listContents = md.getElements(title, "0", "");
                setTitle(title + " - Themes");
                System.out.println(purpose);

            } else if (purpose.contains("*")) {

                System.out.println("Trying to get quotes here guys!");

                int lastSlash = purpose.lastIndexOf("*");
                String extract = purpose.substring(lastSlash + 1,
                        purpose.length());
                System.out.println(extract);
                listContents.clear();
                listContents = md.getQuotes(extract);
                setTitle("Quotes");

            } else if (purpose.contains("/Char/")
                    || purpose.contains("/Theme/")) {
                int lastSlash = purpose.lastIndexOf("/");
                String extract = purpose.substring(lastSlash + 1,
                        purpose.length());
                System.out.println(purpose);
                listContents = md.getPoints(extract, "");
                setTitle(extract);

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not create new MD object");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.genlist_layout);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContents));
    }
```

**`AsyncTask`**

```
private class ImportLitData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        /**
         * ProgressDialog in which progress is shown
         */
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        /**
         * Context of class from which the TXTs will need to be imported -
         * Context of the AsyncTask
         */
        private Activity context;

        /**
         * Boolean to store whether import of data from text file was successful
         * or not
         */

        private Boolean success;

        /**
         * Constructor method
         * 
         * @param dialogIn
         *            Progress Dialog which will be updated
         * @param contextIn
         *            context of Class
         */
        public ImportLitData(ProgressDialog dialogIn, Activity contextIn) {
            // progressDialog = dialogIn;
            context = contextIn;
            setUpDialog();
        }

        /**
         * Sets up the download progress dialog
         */
        private void setUpDialog() {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Importing initial data");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            // progressDialog.show();
        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            System.out.println("do in background!");
            BufferedReader pieceScan;
            BufferedReader specificScan;
            BufferedReader elementScan;
            BufferedReader quoteScan;
            try {
                pieceScan = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        getPieceTextFile(context), "UTF-8"));
                specificScan = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        getSpecificTextFile(context), "UTF-8"));
                elementScan = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        getElementTextFile(context), "UTF-8"));
                quoteScan = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        getQuoteTextFile(context), "UTF-8"));

                openSesame();
                String line;
                String pieceName;
                String isDrama;
                String point;
                String element;
                String quote;
                String isCharacter;
                int commaPoint;
                int commaPoint2;

                System.out.println("INITIAL LAUNCH BLOCK INITIATED");
                while ((line = pieceScan.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("PieceInsertion: ");
                    commaPoint = line.indexOf(",");
                    pieceName = line.substring(0, commaPoint);
                    isDrama = line.substring(commaPoint + 1, commaPoint + 2);
                    ContentValues pv = new ContentValues();
                    pv.put(pieceField, pieceName);
                    pv.put(typeField, (Integer.parseInt(isDrama)));
                    dataBase.insert(pieceTable, null, pv);
                    System.out.println(line
                            + ": INSERTION SHOULD HAVE JUST FINISHED");
                }

                while ((line = specificScan.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("SpecificInsertion: ");
                    commaPoint = line.indexOf(",");
                    point = line.substring(0, commaPoint);
                    commaPoint2 = (line.substring(commaPoint + 1,
                            line.length() - 1).indexOf(",")) + point.length();
                    // pieceName = line.substring(commaPoint + 1,
                    // commaPoint2 +
                    // 1);
                    element = line.substring(commaPoint2 + 2, line.length());

                    ContentValues sv = new ContentValues();
                    sv.put(pointField, point);
                    // sv.put(pieceField, pieceName);
                    sv.put(elementField, element);
                    dataBase.insert(specificTable, null, sv);
                    System.out.println(line
                            + ": INSERTION SHOULD HAVE JUST FINISHED");
                }

                while ((line = elementScan.readLine()) != null) {
                    commaPoint = line.indexOf(",");
                    element = line.substring(0, commaPoint);
                    commaPoint2 = (line.substring(commaPoint + 1,
                            line.length() - 1).indexOf(",")) + element.length();

                    pieceName = line.substring(commaPoint + 1, commaPoint2 + 1);
                    isCharacter = line.substring(commaPoint2 + 2,
                            commaPoint2 + 3);

                    ContentValues ev = new ContentValues();
                    ev.put(elementField, element);
                    ev.put(pieceField, pieceName);
                    ev.put(elTypeField, (Integer.parseInt(isCharacter)));
                    dataBase.insert(elementTable, null, ev);
                    System.out.println(line
                            + ": INSERTION SHOULD HAVE JUST FINISHED");

                }

                while ((line = quoteScan.readLine()) != null) {
                    commaPoint = line.indexOf("^");
                    quote = line.substring(0, commaPoint);
                    System.out.println("Quote = " + quote);
                    point = line.substring(commaPoint + 1, line.length());
                    System.out.println("Point = " + point);

                    ContentValues qv = new ContentValues();
                    qv.put(quoteField, quote);
                    qv.put(pointField, point);
                    dataBase.insert(quoteTable, null, qv);
                    System.out.println(line
                            + ": INSERTION SHOULD HAVE JUST FINISHED");
                }

                success = true;

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                System.out.println("Unsupported Encoding Exception!");
                e.printStackTrace();
                success = false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("IO Exception!");
                e.printStackTrace();
                success = false;
            }

            return success;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            System.out.println("onPostExecute");
            progressDialog.cancel();

            String toastMessage = (result) ? "Imported" : "Import Failed";
            Toast resultOut = Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            resultOut.show();
        }

        /**
         * Method called before doInBackground is executed
         * 
         * @override
         */
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            System.out.println("onPreExecute");
            /* Dialog shown */
            progressDialog.show();

        }

    }
```

**EDIT**
**I've now added the following method to the GenList class (class responsible for ListView)**

```
public void refreshList() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
```

**And now I call the method in onPostExecute**

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            System.out.println("onPostExecute");
            progressDialog.cancel();

            String toastMessage = (result) ? "Imported" : "Import Failed";
            Toast resultOut = Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            resultOut.show();
            genericList.refreshList();
        }
```

**But I am experiencing this error, shown in LogCat output **

```
02-06 20:10:54.723: E/AndroidRuntime(607): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 20:10:54.723: E/AndroidRuntime(607): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 20:10:54.723: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at com.lawson.englishlitrevision.GenList$1.run(GenList.java:312)
02-06 20:10:54.723: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-06 20:10:54.723: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-06 20:10:54.723: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 20:10:54.723: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-06 20:10:54.723: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 20:10:54.723: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-06 20:10:54.723: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-06 20:10:54.723: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-06 20:10:54.723: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Any suggestion why would be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

So you need to get a `notifyDataSetChanged` call to your list view. There's a couple of options for doing this. You can pass the listview into the AsyncTask's constructor, then call it directly in onPostExecute, or you can create a "refreshList" method in your activity (which makes the notifyDataSetChanged call on your listview), and call that method in onPostExecute. I prefer the latter, because it allows you to make other changes you may want to make.

Note that if you create a method in your activity, then you will need to change your constructor to take in that activity specifically to be able to make the call on it, regular Activity wont know about that method.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried your second suggestion, but please see the edit above.

Comment: How and where did you set your adapter? it looks like it's coming up null.

Comment: Set it up in onCreate as:

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContents);